# Are Monolithic Smart Contracts Better than Those That Are Decoupled?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, security, addresses

The smart contract app I am writing follows what I consider good practice - it is decoupled so that a controller contract calls a logic contract which calls a storage contract. So `Contract A` calls `Contract B` calls `Contract C`.

However, I'm wondering if, because of security, such decoupling is a good idea for smart contracts. That's because I need the `onlyOwner` modifier to tie down who calls my functions (as describe here: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features). To my mind, it would be great if I could do something like this:

```
import "Owned.sol";

contract A is Owned {

   B private b;

   function A(address B) {
       b = B(b);
   }

   function myInterface() public onlyOwner {
       a.doStuff({from: msg.sender});
   }
}

contract B is Owned {

   C private c;

   function B(address c) {
       c = C(c);
   }

   function doStuff() public onlyOwner {
       c.store(42,{from: msg.sender});
   }
}

contract C is Owned {

   int private theAnswer;

   function store(int value) public onlyOwner {
       theAnswer = value
   }
}
```

However, I believe I can't send `msg.sender` that way. Hence, would I be better bundling `Contract A`, `Contract B` and `Contract C` into a single monolithic contract where `msg.sender` *is* valid?

Comment: Why don't you just make A the owner of B, and B the owner of C?

Comment: @TjadenHess. I was about to write: "yeah, but how?" But actually, I can pass the address of A to B and B to C in the constructor and assign the owner that way.  Doh! Er, yeah - you're right. Sometimes these things just need airing to be solved ;) Thanks!

Comment: Actually, what I would do is create B in the constructor of A instead of passing in the address, then use `msg.sender` within the constructor of B to set the owner. Then do the same, creating C from within the constructor of B

Comment: @TjadenHess - nice - is that because then B properly owns its instance of C (for example), rather than owning an already deployed C (which might have its ownership changed meanwhile)?

Comment: Exactly. In some cases that may not be what you want, but it's generally easier to reason about the contract when it's not interacting with some arbitrary contract

Comment: I'm remembering now - i was doing it that way, but the reason I'm not doing that now is because I was running out of gas deploying contracts that were doing lots of `new`s. But I know a bit more now, so I'll re-investigate.

Comment: If you're running out of gas, then passing the addresses into the constructor will work fine too

Comment: @TjadenHess So I attempted the `new` approach, and indeed, ran out of gas deploying. It needs around 7M gas. Hence, I need to pass around addresses. Unfortunately, what I didn't realise above is that I can't give the address of B to C so C can make B its owner, since B needs C's address first. There are ways of 'transferring ownership' back to B, but they're all rather messy. That brings me back to the title of my original posting: am I better off avoiding this whole complication by just bundling all of my required functionality into a single contract? I hope not there *must* be better ways...

Answer (score 2):

In the comments to your original post, you have estabilished that deployment of a large monolithic contract may fail due to the block gas limit being reached. A dapp that can't be deployed can't be better. :)

---

As to solutions: maybe extend `Owned` to `Authable` with:

- `mapping (address => bool) public authorised`
- `modifier onlyAuthed {...}`
- `function authAdd (address _addr) public onlyOwner {...}`
- `function authRem (address _addr) public onlyOwner {...}`

... and then use `Authed`+`onlyAuthed` instead of `Owned`+`onlyOwner` in derived dapps?..

You could then deploy the pieces independently. Once there is a "full chain" that can be linked (such as `A->B->C[several]`, you can call `C.authAdd(<address-of-B>)` from your `owner` account.

This is a bit tedious, but relatively easy to automate. In addition to that, you don't have to worry about the order of deployment, or whether some dapps fail to deploy.

The scheme can be modified to suit particular needs.

---

As an alternative, you could use [Zeppelin's Ownable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/Ownable.sol) and its `transfer()` function.

This would work fine if:

- the "ownership chain" is linear, i.e. no case where a dapp could be called by several others; and
- retaining original ownership (by the deploying account) is not needed (e.g. for nuking purposes).

---

EDIT:

Then again, you could move `b = B(b)` out of the constructor to a separate function (like `function createChildren(...) public onlyOwner onlyOnce {...}`), and add some way to propagate the request to already-created children (like `function nagForGrandChildren(...) public onlyOwner {...}`). But the issue remains: if `nFGC()` hits the block gas limit, the function call will have to be repeated - triggered from the original external `owner` account of `A`.

One way or another, you'll need to foresee that some part of your chain will fail to deploy. The choice here is between "something down the line" or "anything in between".