# What do I deploy?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, remix

This is related to [Are Monolithic Smart Contracts Better than Those That Are Decoupled?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9607/are-monolithic-smart-contracts-better-than-those-that-are-decoupled?noredirect=1#comment9906_9607]), where I basically have the following setup:

```
contract A {  
   int private x;          
   function save(int _x) {
       x = _x;
   }
   function get() returns (int) {
       return x;
   }
}

contract B {    
   A private a;    
   function B(address _a) {
       a = A(_a);
   }    
   function doStuff() {
       a.save(42);
   }
   function getStuff()  returns (int) {
       return a.get();
   }
}

contract C {
   B private b;    
   function C(address _b) {
       b = B(_b);
   }
   function calculateTheMeaning() {
      b.doStuff();
   }
   function getTheAnswer() returns (int) {
      return b.getStuff();
   }
}
```

That's working, but rather than pass around the addresses, I'd much prefer to instantiate the contracts:

```
contract A {  
   int private x;          
   function save(int _x) {
       x = _x;
   }
   function get() returns (int) {
       return x;
   }
}

import "A.sol";
contract B {    
   A private a;    
   function B() {
       A a = new A();
   }    
   function doStuff() {
       a.save(42);
   }
   function getStuff()  returns (int) {
       return a.get();
   }
}

import "B.sol";
contract C {
   B private b;    
   function C() {
       B b = new B();
   }
   function calculateTheMeaning() {
      b.doStuff();
   }
   function getTheAnswer() returns (int) {
      return b.getStuff();
   }
}
```

Trouble is, no matter how I do it (`embark blockchain`, http://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/, `testrpc`, whatever), I can't get that to deploy properly - I either get invalid jumps or no results whatsoever.

Currently I have all those contracts in separate files and I was hoping that deploying C.sol alone would suffice (since it includes B which includes A). However, it seems not. I'm doing something wrong, so I'd be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem or not but I think you need  a = new A(); not A a = new A();

Comment: @EdmundEdgar doh! Good spot! That could well be it, couldn't it! I'll keep you posted. Schoolboy error ;)

Comment: Yup - that was it! Doh! I'm off to go stand in the corner with my back to the room :(

Comment: Now someone post and answer and accept it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Eek! So here's where I admit to making a schoolboy error :(

As @EdmundEdgar pointed out, the reason my instantiation of `new` contracts was failing was because the constructors were declaring those `new` contracts as local variables. Hence, the class variables were not having the addresses assigned to them correctly, causing "Invalid Jumps". Here's the corrected code:

```
contract A {  
   int private x;          
   function save(int _x) {
       x = _x;
   }
   function get() returns (int) {
       return x;
   }
}

import "A.sol";
contract B {    
   A private a;    
   function B() {
       a = new A();
   }    
   function doStuff() {
       a.save(42);
   }
   function getStuff()  returns (int) {
       return a.get();
   }
}

import "B.sol";
contract C {
   B private b;    
   function C() {
       b = new B();
   }
   function calculateTheMeaning() {
      b.doStuff();
   }
   function getTheAnswer() returns (int) {
      return b.getStuff();
   }
}
```

Doh!